# Add bearer token selectively to header in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2

I would like to know if there is any option to enable/disable header Interceptor based on a flag or annotation in Retrofit. Since there are few paths in my API that do not need a token, I need to skip adding token to those API calls.

Currently I have a simple Interceptor which will add a header to all the requests that are made from my application

```
//builder is of type OkHttpClient.Builder
builder.addInterceptor(chain -> {
    Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().
    addHeader("authorization", "Bearer foofootoken").build();

    return chain.proceed(request);
});
```

Comment: Just ignore extra parameter in server side.

Answer (score 4):

I have researched this some time ago and I didn't find any solution provided by retrofit out of the box, but you can easily implement a workaround by yourself.

Just annotate the request with a header of your choosing, for example "NoAuth: true" and check for this header in the interceptor:

```
builder.addInterceptor(chain -> {
    String noAuthHeader = chain.request().header("NoAuth");
    Request.Builder request = chain.request().newBuilder();
    if(noAuthHeader == null || !noAuthHeader.equals("true")){
        request.addHeader("authorization", "Bearer foofootoken").build();
    }

    return chain.proceed(request.build());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats how I handle Retrofit with Header and without Token:

```
public class ApiClient {

    private final Retrofit retrofit;

    public ApiClient(String token) {
        if (token.equals("null")) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BaseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        } else {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public Response intercept(@NonNull Chain chain) throws IOException {
                        Request newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token)
                            .build();
                        return chain.proceed(newRequest);
                    }
                })
                .connectTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(client)
                .baseUrl(Constants.BaseURL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
        }

    }

    public ApiInterface getApi() {
        return retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
    }
}
```

And then you can call like this:

```
Call<GetGalleryResponse> call = new ApiClient(new SharePrefManager(this).getAuthToken()).getApi().get_gallery_info("11");
```

or without Header you can call like this:

```
Call<GetGalleryResponse> call = new ApiClient("null").getApi().get_gallery_info("11");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check current path in your interceptor and add token when you find a certain url, so you could do something like this:

```
Request originalRequest = chain.request();
String url = originalRequest.url();
Request.Builder request = originalRequest.newBuilder();
// here try to match your methods who need to add token
if(url.endsWith("/foo")) {
    request.addHeader("authorization", "Bearer foofootoken");
}
chain.proceed(request.build());
```