# how to handle login api without token in interceptors using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, interceptor

I am using retrofit 2.0.2 for HTTP calls in which I have to send token in header for each API except login and signup. For this I have added this token into interceptors and contains information about the client but before login token is automatically added into interceptors. Is there any way to exclude token from interceptors for login and signup call

Answer (score 3):

Check this link out, it contains a nice and clean way to handle this.

https://medium.com/kufar-tech/retrofit-tips-passing-custom-parameters-from-retrofits-request-to-okhttp-s-interceptor-989b8ceff07d

Briefly, you should create a custom annotation (for example named PublicAPI)

```
@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PublicAPI { }
```

and add it to all services that won’t need authentication.

```
public interface LoginService {

    @PublicAPI
    @POST(value = "login")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Void> login(@Header("Authorization") final String credentials);
}
```

Retrofit’s RequestFactory creates an instance of Invocation object with service’s method and argumentList as parameters and sets it as Request tag. Therefore you can check whether your service annotated with PublicAPI or not within the interceptor and do wat you want based on it.

```
@Override
public @NonNull Response intercept(@NonNull final Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request request = chain.request();

    Invocation invocation = request.tag(Invocation.class);
    Annotation publicAPI = invocation.method().getAnnotation(PublicAPI.class);
    if (publicAPI == null) {
        //add access token
    }

    // rest

    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the request path in the interceptor and do some stuff based on the request URL.

```
@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
    Request originalRequest = chain.request();
    if(originalRequest.url().encodedPath().equals("/some/login/path")){
        // don't add token header
    }else{
        // add token header
    }
}
```

or you may use the method provided at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41033670/1273657